# How to serve a fallback file using Iron's staticfile when the original file is not found?

Tags: rust, static-files, iron

I'm using Iron to serve a React site. I'm trying to get it to serve index.html if the file or directory does not exist.

```
fn staticHandler(req: &mut Request) -> IronResult<Response> {
    let url = Url::parse("http://localhost:1393").unwrap();
    let getFile_result = Static::handle(&Static::new(Path::new("../html")), req);

    match getFile_result {
        Ok(_) => getFile_result,
        Err(err) => {
            Static::handle(
                // returns 404 error - ../html/index.html returns 500
                &Static::new(Path::new("localhost:1393/index.html")),
                req,
            )
        }
    }
}
```

If I go to localhost:1393 I get my index page if I go to localhost:1393/not-a-directory I just get an error.

Is there a way to redirect (without changing the url) or some other solution?

This is not a duplicate of [How to change Iron's default 404 behaviour?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43284994/how-to-change-irons-default-404-behaviour) because I'm trying to handle when the static asset the user requests does not exist, not when the route is not defined.

Comment: Since this isn't an answer, Iron does have [static file middleware](https://github.com/iron/staticfile).

Comment: @squiguy I think that's where `Static::new` comes from in this question, but OP didn't provide a [MCVE] so who knows...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed on [staticfile issue #78 titled "Static with fallback"](https://github.com/iron/staticfile/issues/78), you can wrap the handler, check for a 404, and serve a file instead:

```
struct Fallback;

impl AroundMiddleware for Fallback {
    fn around(self, handler: Box<Handler>) -> Box<Handler> {
        Box::new(FallbackHandler(handler))
    }
}

struct FallbackHandler(Box<Handler>);

impl Handler for FallbackHandler {
    fn handle(&self, req: &mut Request) -> IronResult<Response> {
        let resp = self.0.handle(req);

        match resp {
            Err(err) => {
                match err.response.status {
                    Some(status::NotFound) => {
                        let file = File::open("/tmp/example").unwrap();
                        Ok(Response::with((status::Ok, file)))
                    }
                    _ => Err(err),
                }
            }
            other => other
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! That works. It just serves it as plain text. How do you specify that it is an html file?

Comment: Nevermind. I found it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34979970/how-do-i-send-a-file-included-with-include-bytes-as-an-iron-response